# Windows Server 2012-R2/2016 auto login not working

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016

After trying several version of the registry edit way to login automatically (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324737/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows)
I am still unable to make my servers(Windows 2012-R2, Windows 2016) automatically login. What i specifically need is for a program to start up whenever the server boots, and a logged in user is required for the program to function properly. I have followed the links and did as instructed.
[My Registry Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cA5h.png)
As well as change the AutoAdminLogon to 1.
I also tried with the checkbox in User Accounts
(https://superuser.com/questions/499724/auto-login-windows-server-2012)
 
but without luck...

The servers are machines i connect to remotely with a username and password.

Am i misunderstanding both of these methods? 
Is it for some reason impossible when they are remote servers?
Are there any other ways of making the server login?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Anyone stumpling upon this thread later, I found this tiny program.
https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/sysinternals/downloads/autologon
It worked like an absolute charm on my 2012-R2 and 2016 server.

Comment: Can you have more than one user autologon?  Like `User1`, `User2`, `User3` all be set to autologon using the sysinternals tool?